# How to split text separated with "," on new UITableView custom cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Problem Statement:
I want to display text separated by "," on new custom `UITableViewCell`.

Problem: It displays all data in single custom cell only with multi-line  property, as shown in below.

[image]

I want to display tableView like this way.

[image]

Now I'm trying to display above data separated by "," on each new custom cell, as shown in above screenshot, but it displays only 1st data and skip remaining data, as per my code.

```
let Meaning :String = "Aback,Abacus,Abandon,Able,Aboard"
let Smeaning :String = "Fabric,Habit,keen,Pace"

func tableView(tableViewData: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableViewData.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as! StudentCell

    let fmeaning = Mmeaning.characters.split{$0 == ","}.map(String.init)
            let smeaning = Hmeaning.characters.split{$0 == ","}.map(String.init)

    for var i = 0; i < fmeaning.count; i += 1{
        print(fmeaning[i])  
        //Here it prints all values perfectly
    }
    for var i = 0; i < smeaning.count; i += 1{
        print(smeaning[i])
        //Here it prints all values perfectly
    }
```

Problem occurs here below two statements: display only 1st value in `UITableView`

```
    cell.lblMeaning1.text = fmeaning[indexPath.row] 
    cell.lblMeaning2.text = smeaning[indexPath.row]
    return cell;
}
```

How should I assign an `Array` to these two custom cells, so that it will display data on separate new custom cell?

Comment: What is your cell's height?

Comment: I'm using this function heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @Ashish Both array contain equal elements ?

Comment: No, both varies

Comment: With this two custom cells I'm displaying as two columns in tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to use section table with your `tableView`, also you need to make this calculation in `viewDidLoad` and then reload the `tableView`, For that declare your two instance of array like this in your `viewController`.

```
var languageDic = [String: [String]]()
var allLanguage = [String]()    

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let mMeaningArray = Mmeaning.characters.split{$0 == ","}.map(String.init)
    let hMeaningArray = Hmeaning.characters.split{$0 == ","}.map(String.init)
    self.languageDic = ["Marathi Meaning": mMeaningArray,"Hindi Meaning": hMeaningArray] // You can add other langaue in the dic sam way I have added this two
    self.allLanguage = Array(self.languageDic.keys) as [String]
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.allLanguage.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String {
    return self.allLanguage[indexPath.section]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {        
    return self.languageDic[self.allLanguage[section]].count  
}

func tableView(tableViewData: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableViewData.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as! StudentCell
    let str = self.languageDic[self.allLanguage[indexPath.section]][indexPath.row]
    cell.lblMeaning1.text = str
    return cell
}
```

**Note:** In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you need only one label.

**Edit:** As of you want return the count of array that have more element you can try like this. F

```
var mMeaningArray = [String]()
var hMeaningArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.mMeaningArray = Mmeaning.characters.split{$0 == ","}.map(String.init)
    self.hMeaningArray = Hmeaning.characters.split{$0 == ","}.map(String.init)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {        
    return (self.mMeaningArray.count > self.hMeaningArray.count)? self.mMeaningArray.count : self.hMeaningArray.count  
}

func tableView(tableViewData: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableViewData.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as! StudentCell
    if indexPath.row < self.mMeaningArray.count {
        cell.lblMeaning1.text = self.mMeaningArray[indexPath.row]
    }
    else {
        cell.lblMeaning1.text = ""
    }
    if indexPath.row < self.hMeaningArray.count {
        cell.lblMeaning2.text = self.hMeaningArray[indexPath.row]
    }
    else {
        cell.lblMeaning2.text = ""
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Not yet, some how it works, but in cellForRowAtIndexPath, this function can't access "section" so I have run only single "if-statement". And I require result in two separate columns vertically. I want to show both the columns result at a time.

Comment: @Ashish That was my mistake, forgot to add `indexPath.`. Please check the edited answer. Also if you want to show multiple language i will update the answer with dynamic section if you want.

Comment: Yes, sure I want multiple language answer, as I've shown in my screenshot in my problem statement, similar to Hindi-Marathi columns like tableView.

Comment: Thanks your edited answer works for me, it shows me result in horizontal format, is it possible to show it in vertically same as table format with two columns.

Comment: Your arrays doesn't contain equal elements so it is quite difficult.

Comment: Can we assign only that section whose count is greater to numberOfRowsInSection. Example: if section1.count > section2.count Then  return section1

Comment: I have edited answer for dynamic section for your above comment let me check first and then i will update the answer.

Comment: Also there is one problem in your previous edited answer, when I scroll-up UITableViewCell, then section1 title won't scroll and section2 title scroll till section1

Comment: Can you show the screen shot of that and check the edited answer, I think you want something like this.

Comment: Yes, it finally works, as per your recent edited answer. This is what I required. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome mate :) Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hi, now there is one more problem related to this, your code works fine but when there is large string then it hiding with "..." this. I want that it should be multi-line so it would adjust bottom and custom cell height should be dynamically increase.

Comment: Follow this tutorial this will solve your problem. https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: Please tell me how can I share screenshot with you.

Comment: Add new question with more detail and new code that you have use, also add screenshot with in that question.

Answer (score 0):

the `numberOfRowsInSection()` function should return `fmeaning.count` and `smeaning.count`... put an if to determine which table you want to have the correct row number.

also you cand display the `fmeaning` as a section in your tableview, and the `smeaning` as cells.

Comment: How should I return both count in "numberOfRowsInSection" function, and I want to display both as cells.